# I want to scream and can but...don't?

Tags: phrase-requests

I have been having a frustrating past few weeks and I always come to the point where I want to yell, shout, or scream. The sad part is I feel it rest in my throat and then disappear. I know this may sound stupid but is there a word or phrase for that?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Yes, sure, the phrase is 'a lump in one's throat' ("a feeling of tightness or pressure in the throat due to emotion", [*OED*](https://oed.com/)). As in your case, "I was so frustrated I felt a lump in my throat."

Answer (score 0):

**speechless**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/speechless)

> adj temporarily incapable of speaking “speechless with shock”

As in:

> So surprised, in fact, that I was rendered, for a moment, **speechless**.
>   *A Very Large Expanse of Sea*

If you’re speechless, you can’t talk, usually because something surprising and crazy happened. You might be rendered speechless, or at a loss for words when under duress, agast or thunderstruck.